# Using Count with Group Concat

Tags: mysql, sql, database, count

[Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/271eb/1)

I have a page that lists multiple polls and all of their vote options from table `vote_option`. I use the table `user_vote` to store the users' vote records. I want to retrieve from that table the vote result for each vote option in each poll. Can anyone show me how to use `GROUP_CONCAT` with `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_vote GROUP BY product_id` so that the result would be like this:

```
Poll_TITLE   VOTE_OPTION                     IMG                VOTE_COUNT <---how to get this column 
Title A      Product A,Product B,Product C   imgA,imgB,imgC     2,0,1  
Title B      Product A,Product B,Product D   imgA,imgB,imgD     0,1,0
Title C      Product D,Product E             imgD,imgE          1,0
```

Table Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE poll
    (`poll_id` int,`title`varchar(30))
;

INSERT INTO poll
    (`poll_id`,`title`)
VALUES
    (1,'Title A'),
    (2,'Title B'),
    (3,'Title C')

;

CREATE TABLE product
    (`product_id` int,`product_name` varchar(30),`img`varchar(30))
;

INSERT INTO product
    (`product_id`,`product_name`,`img`)
VALUES
    (1,'Product A','imgA'),
    (2,'Product B','imgB'),
    (3,'Product C','imgC'),
    (4,'Product D','imgD'),
    (5,'Product E','imgE')
;

CREATE TABLE vote_option
    (`poll_id` int,`product_id` int)
;

INSERT INTO vote_option
    (`poll_id`,`product_id`)
VALUES
    (1,1),
    (1,2),
    (1,3),
    (2,1),
    (2,2),
    (2,4),
    (2,2),
    (3,4),
    (3,5)

;

CREATE TABLE user_vote
    (`poll_id` int,`product_id` int,`user_id` int)
;

INSERT INTO user_vote
    (`poll_id`,`product_id`,`user_id`)
VALUES
    (1,1,1),
    (1,1,2),
    (1,3,2),
    (2,2,1),
    (3,4,1)
;

CREATE TABLE user
    (`user_id` int,`user_name` varchar (30))
;

INSERT INTO user
    (`user_id`,`user_name`)
VALUES
    (1,'Tom'),
    (2,'Sally')
;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to aggregate the data first at a more granular level to get the counts, and then re-aggregate at the poll level:

```
SELECT title,
       GROUP_CONCAT(product_name) as products,
       GROUP_CONCAT(img) as imgs,
       GROUP_CONCAT(cnt) as cnt
FROM (SELECT p.poll_id, p.title, pr.product_name, img, count(distinct uv.user_id) as cnt
      FROM vote_option v INNER JOIN
           poll p
           ON p.poll_id = v.poll_id INNER JOIN
           product pr
           ON pr.product_id = v.product_id LEFT JOIN
           user_vote uv
           ON uv.product_id = v.product_id AND
              uv.poll_id = v.poll_id LEFT JOIN
           user u
           ON uv.user_id = u.user_id
      GROUP BY p.poll_id, p.title, pr.product_name, img
     ) p
GROUP BY title
LIMIT 0, 25;
```

Note that you can put the data into a single list using something like:

```
SELECT title,
       GROUP_CONCAT(product_name, ',', img, ',', cnt separator '; ')
```

And by using an `order by` clause in the `group_concat()`, you can have the highest vote-getter first in the list.

Comment: the result that I've got isn't accurate. [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f682/17). I have changed `count(*) as cnt` to `count(uv.product_id) as cnt`. The first and thrid rows are correct, but the second one isn't. [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f682/23)

Comment: Just modify the query to order the concatenated elements like: `SELECT title,
           GROUP_CONCAT(product_name order by pid) as products,
           GROUP_CONCAT(img order by pid) as imgs,
           GROUP_CONCAT(cnt order by pid) as cnt
    FROM (SELECT p.poll_id, p.title, pr.product_name,pr.product_id pid, img, count(uv.product_id) as cnt` [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f682/33)

Comment: @dan Any idea why the second row (title B) adds one extra count to product B? [Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f682/36)? The user_vote table only has five rows, but the total vote count is six.

Comment: @RedGiant . . . Something in the joins appears to be causing a small cartesian product.  The expression `count(distinct uv.user_id)` seems to fix the problem.

Comment: @RedGiant . . . The problem is your data, which has two values of `(2,2)` in the `vote_option` table.